# cloning a repository using hg mercurial in MacOS gives an abort error : "abort: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, mercurial

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:IpadProject apple$ hg clone https://code.google.com/p/comicflow/
warning: code.google.com certificate with fingerprint 99:9b:2c:ac:bf:65:cc:74:61:df:ed:05:6d:f6:22:a9:d6:e1:ba:9f not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
destination directory: comicflow
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 23 changesets with 131 changes to 75 files
updating to branch default
warning: cooliris-toolkit.googlecode.com certificate with fingerprint 3c:e9:db:04:ed:73:73:f7:dd:cb:e0:20:ce:77:28:5d:a3:d2:32:3f not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
cloning subrepo Cooliris-ToolKit from https://cooliris-toolkit.googlecode.com/hg/
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 145 changesets with 631 changes to 381 files
abort: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Care to improve your question? Check [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) to know how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because Git is not installed on your Mac.

You need to install both Mercurial and Git to checkout ComicFlow source code.

PS: I added instructions on how to check out ComicFlow project in my answer to this question:
[How to fix a Mercurial repo that fails updating because points to missing revision in subrepo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946320/how-to-fix-a-mercurial-repo-that-fails-updating-because-points-to-missing-revisi)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a hook in your global config file that does not really exist.

You can check by running:

```
hg clone THEREPO -v --traceback  --debugger
```

which will start pdb and you can debug from the exception point.

[reference](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/cant-clone-repo-abort-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of the 'No such file or directory' error is when the file path exceeds 255 characters. I had to shorten some directory names to get it working in my case.